# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Files already present in the current directory

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to run execute this command through python subprocess. My current directory contains folder splitta103 which has both the sbd.py file and model_nb folder.

python splitta103/sbd.py -m splitta103/model_nb info.txt

This is my python program

```
file = 'info.txt'

print(subprocess.check_output(['splitta103','/','sbd.py','-m','splitta103','/','model_nb',file]))
```

Here is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-743654b05145> in <module>()
     12 text_file = 'info.txt'
     13 
---> 14 print(subprocess.check_output(['splitta103','/','sbd.py','-m','splitta103','/','model_nb','info.txt']))
     15 #print(subprocess.check_output(['sbd.py','-m','model_nb','info.txt']))
     16 

/home/joe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    210     if 'stdout' in kwargs:
    211         raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
--> 212     process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    213     output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    214     retcode = process.poll()

/home/joe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    388                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    389                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 390                                 errread, errwrite)
    391         except Exception:
    392             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/home/joe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1023                         raise
   1024                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1025                 raise child_exception
   1026 
   1027 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `print(subprocess.check_output(['splitta103','/','sbd.py','-m','splitta103','/','model_nb','info.txt']))`

Would look like: `splitta103 / sbd.py -m splitta103 / model_nb info.txt` on the command line.

This on the command line: `python splitta103/sbd.py -m splitta103/model_nb info.txt`

Can be produced with this: `['python', 'splitta103/sbd.py', '-m', 'splitta103/model_nb', 'info.txt']`